# I want to get the contact numbers without duplication in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Can anyone give me advice on how to find a records mobile no without duplicates from my [student table]?

I tried to find a solution using the query designer, but I failed. Please give me a proper solution.

Comment: Inside the query designer each query also has properties.  if you choose true for the unique values property then distinct is added to the sql the query writes which gives you unique records.  see here for more details about how to use select distinct in access: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use `distinct`:

```
select distinct [Mobile Phone] from [student table]
```

Comment: actually I have multiple fields and I want to apply DISTINCT only on [Mobile] field but DISTINCT not support multiple values.

Comment: It does. In fact it will be applied to _all_ fields returned, thus all returned records will be unique.

Comment: Also review how to use distinct in sql.  the link in my previous comment has one example of how to customize which records are distinct.